# MySQL connection impossible with good password

Tags: mysql

When I try to connect to mysql server with :

> mysql -u user -ppassword

I get the following error message :

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'corp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But when using this :

> mysql -u user -p
>
> enter password: password

It works !

I'm an hundred percent sure of the password, I know it is the good one.
I tried with several users, with the option :

- -h localhost or
- -h 127.0.0.1 or
- -h hostname or
- -h @IP

I've deleted anonymous users too, I've almost no hair left.. Someone has an idea ? I'm sure it is simple as duck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that you have characters in the pw that get intercepted by the shell (e.g. `$`)

Try

```
mysql --password='your-password'
```

(put into single quotes) and read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html to learn why this problem is only one reason why putting the password into the command line is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank GOD it is that ! Thank you very much !

I know that it is a bad idea but I need it for a script that connect to mysql to dump a DB.

Comment: You can supply the password in a file even for scripts. See the `--defaults-file` and `--login-path` options for `mysql` ([doc link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file)).

Comment: you can just also try with -p'password' it's the same and works fine, same as -p 'password', but always enclose your password with single quotes, as Vince said